# How to include non-key attributes in dynamodb table and assign values to it using batch_writer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Creating a table using dynamodb with hash and Range keys. Also, i have some non-key attributes and it's values to be included in it. Getting error while trying to update the table.

Code:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

table = dynamodb.Table('Name')
db_AccountNumber=[]  #data to be included in table is in below two lists which consists of multiple 12 digit AWS account-ID's.

db_accountalias=[]  #data contains multiple AWS account-names

# Create the DynamoDB table.
table = dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName='Name',
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'account_number',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'account_type',
            'KeyType': 'RANGE'
        }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'account_number',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'account_type',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 10,
    }
)

table.meta.client.get_waiter('table_exists').wait(TableName='Name')


with table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for item in db_AccountNumber:
        for alias in db_accountalias:
            batch.put_item(
                Item={
                     'account_number' : item,
                     'account_type' : 'new',
                     'iam_alias': {'S': alias},
                     'profile': {'S': alias},
                     'cname': {'S': alias}
            }
     )
```

I want the non-key attributes `iam_alias`, `profile`,`cname` to have the same values as of now.

Executing above codes gives Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./createdb_multiplefields.py", line 66, in <module>
    'cname': {'S': alias}
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/dynamodb/table.py", line 101, in put_item
    self._add_request_and_process({'PutRequest': {'Item': Item}})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/dynamodb/table.py", line 110, in _add_request_and_process
    self._flush_if_needed()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/dynamodb/table.py", line 131, in _flush_if_needed
    self._flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/dynamodb/table.py", line 137, in _flush
    RequestItems={self._table_name: items_to_send})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation: Provided list of item keys contains duplicates
```

Clearly, the keys in my Item are not duplicate. How to fix this error and update table?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that you have duplicate keys. Your problem is in this piece of code:

```
with table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for item in db_AccountNumber:
        for alias in db_accountalias:
            batch.put_item(
                Item={
                     'account_number' : item,
                     'account_type' : 'new',
                     'iam_alias': {'S': alias},
                     'profile': {'S': alias},
                     'cname': {'S': alias}
            }
     )
```

On the first execution of the inner loop `for alias in db_accountalias:` your `account_number` is set to value of `item` and `account_type` is set to `'new'`. On the second execution of the same loop, the `account_number` is still set to value of `item` (since you are still within the context of the inner loop) and similarly `account_type` is also still set to `'new'`, since it's a constant value, that is not changing as the inner loop iterates. As a result, you are getting the duplicate key value, which is what the error message indicates.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to enter data to table.I replaced two for-loop statements `for item in db_AccountNumber:

for alias in db_accountalias:`  with just one for loop like below.

`for item, alias in zip(db_AccountNumber, db_accountalias):` which did the trick.